# @Html.Raw to general javascript function call error if variable with white space

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am new to MVC and Razor engine. Trying to output the below string using @Html.Raw but the expected result is different.

```
@Html.Raw("&nbsp;<span class='label label-warning' style='cursor: pointer' onclick=ChangeRPLocStatus(2,1,'1160001','1160001','X','Test 1')>AABBCC</span>")
```

**Output in Html :**

```
<span class="label label-warning" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="ChangeRPLocStatus(2,1,'1160001','1160001','X','Test" 1')="">AABBCC</span>
```

**The output is different at "Test 1".**

I am expecting to get :

```
ChangeRPLocStatus(2,1,'1160001','1160001','X',Test 1')
```

but it become :

```
ChangeRPLocStatus(2,1,'1160001','1160001','X','Test" 1')=""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing it is because `onclick=ChangeRPLocStatus(2,1,'1160001','1160001','X','Test 1')` doesn't have quotes around the js method call. Try this?

```
onclick=\"ChangeRPLocStatus(2,1,'1160001','1160001','X','Test 1')\"
```

Also, a little tip, did you get the output from the actual source (Ctrl + U in chrome) or via Dev Tools or Firebug, they can be different an cause confusion.

Comment: Hi SimonGates, thank you. that solve my problem. Puzzle me is that if there is no space between "Text 1", like if it is "Test1", the code will just work.
I am using IE inspect element to get the HTML code.

Comment: Sometimes it's worth looking at the raw HTML rather than the using Developer Tools to view the HTML as there can be subtle differences in the HTML they display.... especially with quotes as they like to add them in where they don't exist.